# How can I get field's value without getting whole document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

It seems to be really stupid question, I know. But anyway.

Lats say, I have collection of documents of such structure:

```
{
  _id: idvalue, 
  name: namevalue, 
  location: 
  {
    long: longvalue, 
    lat: latvalue
  }
}
```

And, of course, serialized class in C#.

I need to get location of document specified by it's _id.

I've tried to do this in following way:

```
var documentLocation = collection.FindOne("_id", new ObjectId(id)).Location;
```

But in this case the whole document will be taken from db. And I want to take only "location: {long: longvalue, lat: latvalue}" part of json.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Find` instead of `FindOne`. `FindOne` internally call Find method as follows:

```
return Find(query).SetLimit(1).FirstOrDefault()
```

That means that you can't change `MongoCursor` via `FindOne`. But to specify what fields driver should return (via `SetFields`) you need access to mongo cursor.

Also when you specify fields driver still returns entire object (not just location) but all fields except specified will be null/empty.

So, a final query:

```
var documentLocation = collection.Find("_id", new ObjectId(id))
                                 .SetFields(Fields.Include("Location"))
                                // single if you sure that this document always in db
                                 .Single() 
                                 .Location;
```

Also driver will always return the `_id` field even if you not specify it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to use Find, but I was confused about SetField, because I thought it just assigns some value to specified field. Now its purpose clear for me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that with a Cursor and the setFields method on the Mongo cursor object.

```
var cursor = collection.FindAs<DocType>(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(id));
cursor.SetFields(Fields.Include("location");
var items = cursor.ToList();
```

Now I'm not 100% sure that will work exactly correctly but it should be in the neighborhood.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn! I've understood the basic idea. SetField() was not clear for me, but now it is ok.